# GIt: have to push twice (or more)

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I use git+ssh on win7 machine. When I type 'git push', it sometime send commit to server, and sometime not. And every time I can't understand, was it sended or not. Why it happends and what can I do to fix it?

```
D:\project>git push
Counting objects: 56, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 3.83 KiB, done.
Total 29 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

D:\project>git push
Counting objects: 56, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 3.83 KiB, done.
Total 29 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

D:\project>git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: I guess, your server process is having troubles. Low memory situation?

Comment: I don't think so, because the same commands on linux work well.

Comment: Version mismatch or something that may make the server hangup on the input sent from Windows git?

Comment: My local git version is latest, 1.7.7. How can I check your suggestions? Do git have any test commands? BTW, thank you for help.

Comment: Is your remote using ssh:// protocol? The Windows git client (msysgit) can be buggy with SSH and Git protocols, but tends to work better (albeit slower) with HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Yes, it's ssh. As I understand, it's repository setting, not my choice. BTW, version 1.7.7.1-beta works well at the moment. Maybe it was temporary bug.